# Should Facebook ios sdk's static library appear inside Xcode Project?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I'm currently doing facebook integration and have gone through this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#register). So far, I've done everything until step #2.

To test the single sign - on, I decided to implement it in Paul Heggarty's [Photomania](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Photomania_0.zip) project. To do this, as said by the tutorial linked above, I should clone the git hub repository (under step 2). I've done this by copy and pasting `git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git`
  on my Terminal and it works fine. I can locate where the `facebook-ios-sdk` folder is in. Great, so I dragged the folder to the Photomania project.

Also stated in the tutorial that I should make a static library for the facebook-ios-sdk if I enabled `Automatic Reference Counting` for the App (Photomania). Which is what I did after discovering through streaming back to the Core Data Demo video that Photomania actually enabled ARC. So now, I did the static library by copy and pasting this `~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh` to my Terminal. Upon doing so, it actually created the new library.

However, I can't see the `lib` folder inside `facebook-ios-sdk` (already copied in the Photomania). Even though through Finder I can locate the project Photomania, see the `facebook-ios-sdk`'s `lib` folder in it with the Static library.

Enlighten me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, Xcode and the finder have completely independent file systems (assuming you are not checking the "copy files (if needed)" option).  When you drag a file from the finder to an Xcode project, they are copied and placed under the "Copy Bundle Resources" tab, while still retaining the general file-structure that you dragged inside the Xcode file tree.  So therefore, updates to finder files necessitate the new file(s) being dragged into the Xcode file tree.  Simple as that.

Comment: I see, so what I did is just normal? I also found out that after copying `facebook-ios-sdk` inside the XCode project, then run the code to make a static library, that folder also get updated.

Comment: Yes, it's actually quite common.  Xcode's file enumeration is very very strict.

Comment: Alrights! I'll go proceed learning this FB integration. Thanks! :)